# Error uploading image (in bytes) to a HTTP server

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload an image (in bytes) from a HTTP server. I am encountering an error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when using the code below. Please hellp

```
                string image = @"C:\.....\helloX2.pdf";
                byte[] ImageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(image);
                Uri _uri = new Uri(@"http://XXX.XXX.XX.X:8080/MyHTTPFileServer/helloX2.pdf");

                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                byte[] responseArray = client.UploadData(_uri, "POST",ImageData);
                string x = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
                client.Dispose();
```

Comment: Did the server give a reason? Is it your server? Can you debug it?

Comment: I am not seeing any logs from the server side of the HTTP file server. There is this outer exception message "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." from my application. DownloadData and UploadFile methods are working

Comment: @Teemer as wrote in my answer, try my method in the answer, its working for sure, if your still getting this message, you must debug the server side! maybe a connection timeout? you need some logs there.

Answer (score 0):

As you are being told in the message `the connection is closed by you server`!
So what you should do next is:

1. If you can debugger your server, put a `break-point` or a log in the entrance of the upload API method.
2. If not reaching there you can see if the reqeust even got to your server, for example if using an `IIS` server you can see in the `IIS` logs if the reqeust even received, maybe a connection error?? try using tools like `postman or fiddler` first to make sure you have a connection.

Also I am attaching a wrapper code I wrote for an `HttpClient` Upload:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(
string url, 
byte[] fileContent,
string fileName,
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers = null,
int timeoutMili = 30000)
{
    HttpResponseMessage retVal = null;
    HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = null;

    try
    {
        //ssl
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = m_SecurityProtocolType;

        //proxy
        if (m_Proxy != null)
        {
            httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = m_Proxy
            };
        }

        //create the request
        using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
                content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileContent)), fileName, fileName);
                request.Content = content;

                if (headers != null)
                {
                    foreach (var header in headers)
                    {
                        request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                    }
                }

                //send the request
                var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource(timeoutMili);
                retVal = await client.SendAsync(request, cancelToken.Token);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I tested the wrapper method without defining a proxy. The log in the HTTP File server (I use HFS, I created the File Server in my personal laptop) is "1:46:07 PM 192.168.49.3:60134 Requested POST /MyHTTPFileServer/". Is the wrapper method supposedly will upload the file already? Here is the code. string url = @"http://192.168.49.3:8080/MyHTTPFileServer/";
                    string image = @"C:\Users\osmtft\Desktop\Teemee\helloX2.pdf";
                    byte[] ImageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(image);
                    UploadFile(url, ImageData, "helloX2.pdf");

Comment: what status you receive on the client side?

Comment: No exception or any error encountered. What will be the next steps?

Comment: No exceptions its nice, did you make sure you got 200 status code??

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way on how to dump physical files from Azure File Storage to HTTP File server. I did find a indirect way though.

Comment: What is the indirect way?

Comment: This can be done in our current setup. Save the file in bytes in the database. Create a CLR method to be use in MS SQL Server that gets the bytes and convert it to a physical file then dump the file in the expose shared path of the file server. Create a SQL trigger that calls the CLR method and that triggers when a document details is saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

We fix this issue my implementing this process.

1. We created an API with bytes as a parameter inside an existing web app that is deployed internally.
2. Our app then calls the API sending the files' bytes.
3. The API then converts the bytes into PDF.